# Hibernate-search OneToMany infinite indexing

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

all help/comments appreciated

I've got a @OneToMany relationship.
TVenue and TVenueItem
I want to be able to search on various fields on Venue so I've marked it with @Indexed.
My setup is as so:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class TVenue  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Set<TVenueItem> TVenueItems = new HashSet<TVenueItem>(0);

    .......
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="TVenue")
    public Set<TVenueItem> getTVenueItems() {
        return this.TVenueItems;
    }
    ...........
```

and

```
@Entity
public class TVenueItem  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String name;
    private TVenue TVenue;

    ...........
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="venue_id", nullable=false)
    public TVenue getTVenue() {
        return this.TVenue;
    }

    @Field
    @Column(name="_name", nullable=false, length=100)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    .......
```

No problems so far.

Now, completely independently I want to search on fields of TVenueItem so I mark it as @Indexed also.

The problem: As soon as I add @Indexed to TVenueItem the (manual) indexing hangs forever presumably because or infinite recursion.

Anyone know how to avoid this problem?
I understand that TVenue is the owning entity and operations on TVenueItem can be done from TVenue.
However, I'd like to be able to search on TVenueItem independently regardless.

Thanks Very Much

J

Comment: You are not showing which fields you are actually indexing (@Field) and in particular whether you are using @IndexedEmbedded. If you use the latter you might indeed need to use the depth parameter to avoid endless recursions. Do you eventually run out of memory?

Comment: The only field being indexed is TVenuItem.name. there is no usage of @IndexEmbedded. The situation above is exactly what fails. I've never left it long enough to run out of memory. HAve left it up to 1 minute with literally 1 or 2 items/rows of data. However,you're correct, some of the story is missing. I'm using Spring. When I take away anything Spring related from the indexing it the problem goes away. Transactional was not the problem, I haven't yet found exactly what the cause is, when I do, I'll post the answer here. Diff between Spring and Hbn setup.. not sure yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've found some solution. Try use something like this:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class TVenue  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Set<TVenueItem> TVenueItems = new HashSet<TVenueItem>(0);

    .......
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="TVenue")
    @IndexedEmbedded(prefix = "tvenue.item")
    public Set<TVenueItem> getTVenueItems() {
        return this.TVenueItems;
    }
    ...........
```

And:

```
@Entity
public class TVenueItem  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String name;
    private TVenue TVenue;

    ...........
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="venue_id", nullable=false)
    @ContainedIn
    public TVenue getTVenue() {
        return this.TVenue;
    }

    @Field
    @Column(name="_name", nullable=false, length=100)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    .......
```

For more  information [look here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.2/reference/en/html/search-mapping.html)